# HTTP Post Method in my mobile app appends unknown string (from Nomadix?)

Tags: android, ios, security, networking

I have this iOS and Android application which sends simple data to my server. Everything works fine. But there is this one guy using iOS that cannot send correct data to my server. Somewhere along the way, this weird javascript appears. I tried to packet capture the data on the receiving end and saw this added to my POST data:

```
<!-- NdxICC, languageOption=0, charsetOption=0 -->
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<SCRIPT Language="JavaScript">
var usgDebugOn = false;
var iccConsoleOption = 0;
var iccLocation = 0;
</SCRIPT>
<!-- ************************ -->
<!-- *      NdxICC.htm      * -->
<!-- ************************ -->
<!-- * 2005-12-22  BPHolmen * -->
<!-- ************************ -->

<Script Language='JavaScript'>
var jsVersion = 1.0;
</Script>
<Script Language='JavaScript1.1'>
var jsVersion = 1.1;
</Script>
<Script Language='JavaScript1.2'>
var jsVersion = 1.2;
</Script>
<Script Language='JavaScript1.3'>
var jsVersion = 1.3;
</Script>

<Head>
<Title>Launch the Nomadix Console</Title>
</Head>

<Script Language='JavaScript'>
if (usgDebugOn) alert('NdxICC...');
if (usgDebugOn) alert('jsVersion='+jsVersion);

    window.name = '_NdxBrowser';

var docURL = window.location.href;
if (usgDebugOn) alert(docURL);

    var x1 = 0;
    var x2 = 0;

    // IP = USG IP Address ...
    var strIP = '';
    x1 = docURL.indexOf('IP=',x1);
    if (x1 > 0)
    {
        x1 += 3;
        x2 = docURL.indexOf('&',x1);
        if (x2 < 1) { x2 = docURL.length; }
        strIP = unescape(docURL.substring(x1,x2));
    }
    if (usgDebugOn) alert('strIP='+strIP);

    // MA = MAC Address ...
    var strMA = '';
    x1 = docURL.indexOf('MA=',x1);
    if (x1 > 0)
    {
        x1 += 3;
        x2 = docURL.indexOf('&',x1);
        if (x2 < 1) { x2 = docURL.length; }
        strMA = unescape(docURL.substring(x1,x2));
    }
    if (usgDebugOn) alert('strMA='+strMA);

    // OS = Origin Server
    var strOS = '';
    x1 = docURL.indexOf('OS=',x1);
    if (x1 > 0)
    {
        x1 += 3;
        x2 = docURL.indexOf('&',x1);
        if (x2 < 1) { x2 = docURL.length; }
        strOS = unescape(docURL.substring(x1,x2));
        if (strOS.substring(0,7) != 'http://')
        {
            strOS = 'http://' + strOS;
        }
    } else {
        x1 = 0;
    }
    if (usgDebugOn) alert('strOS='+strOS);

    // are we running on MSIE? if so, what version?
    var appVersion = 0;
    var idxMSIE = navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE');
    if (0 <= idxMSIE)
    {
        var idxChr1 = navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' ',idxMSIE+1);
        var idxChr2 = navigator.userAgent.indexOf(';',idxChr1+1);
        if (idxMSIE < idxChr1 && idxChr1 < idxChr2)
        {
            appVersion = navigator.userAgent.substring(idxChr1+1,idxChr2) - 0;
        }
    }

    var defaultWidth  = 420;
    var defaultHeight = 180;

    if (usgDebugOn) {
        defaultHeight *= 2;
    }


// WinCE screen size = 240x320
var scrWidth  = 240;
var scrHeight = 320;

    if ((jsVersion >= 1.2) && (screen != null))
    {
        if (screen.width > 0 && screen.height > 0)
        {
            scrWidth  = screen.width;
            scrHeight = screen.height;
        }
    }

    // allow for scroll bar
    scrWidth  -= 20;

    if (usgDebugOn) alert('Screen=(' + scrWidth + 'x' + scrHeight + ')');

var winWidth;
var winHeight;

    if (defaultWidth < scrWidth)
    {   // rectangle, for wide screens
        winWidth  = defaultWidth;
        winHeight = defaultHeight;
    }
    else
    {   // square, for small screens
        winWidth  = scrWidth;
        winHeight = scrWidth;
    }

    if (usgDebugOn) alert('NdxICC.winWidth  = '+winWidth);
    if (usgDebugOn) alert('NdxICC.winHeight = '+winHeight);

var winFeat = 'Resizable=no,Scrollbars=no,Status=no,Toolbar=no';
    winFeat += (',Width=' + winWidth + ',Height=' + winHeight);

    // Window Position ...
    // ... Upper Left (default)
    var vLeft = 0;
    var vTop  = 0;
    if (iccConsoleOption != 0)
    {   // Logout Popup
        switch (iccLocation)
        {
            case 0:
                // Upper Left
                break;
            case 1:
                // Upper Right
                vLeft = (scrWidth  - winWidth);
                break;
            case 2:
                // Lower Left
                vTop  = (scrHeight - winHeight);
                break;
            case 3:
                // Lower Right
                vLeft = (scrWidth  - winWidth);
                vTop  = (scrHeight - winHeight);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        // allow room for status bar at bottom of screen
        vTop -= 65;
    }
    // ... Sanity check
    vLeft = (vLeft < 0) ? 0 : vLeft;
    vTop  = (vTop  < 0) ? 0 : vTop;
    // ... Window Position
    winFeat += (',Left=' + vLeft + ',Top=' + vTop);

    winHREF  = ('http://' + strIP + ':2111/usg/NdxBegin.htm');
    winHREF += ('?IP=' + escape(strIP));
    winHREF += ('&MA=' + escape(strMA));
    winHREF += ('&OS=' + escape(strOS));
    winHREF += ('&width='  + winWidth);
    winHREF += ('&height=' + winHeight);

    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Windows CE') < 0)
    {
        if (usgDebugOn) alert('NOT Windows CE');
        window.open(winHREF,'_NdxICC',winFeat);
    }
    else
    {
        if (usgDebugOn) alert('Windows CE');
        window.location.replace(winHREF);
    }
</Script>

<Body onLoad='window.open(strOS,"_NdxBrowser");'>
<Script Language='JavaScript'>
    document.writeln('<' + 'Img Src="http://' + strIP + ':3111/Nomadix.bmp">');
</Script>
</Body>

<!-- ************************ -->
<!-- * eof: NdxICC.htm      * -->
<!-- ************************ -->
```

I never added those strings. I suspect the guy's phone is a company phone with very tight security setup by their IT team. I've googled and found no posts that discusses this issue. Can somebody please direct me to a good solution?

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes see the same thing. My understanding is that this is an error message that gets returned when the user is behind a firewall that's preventing some outgoing connections.

I also have an app that makes outgoing connections, and very occasionally this is the HTML that gets returned as a response. I bet that if this was viewed in browser, it would show an error message/explanation served from that firewall. In my case, I think the user who was getting this was on a hospital's WiFi, so that would make sense.

Comment: yeah, this is my impression as well. or the user is using a vpn app maybe.